# Scanning Binary Search Tree vs Array

Tags: arrays, caching, tree, operating-system

> In what ways would finding an element (traverse) in a BST be slower than linearly scanning for it within an array?

The answer supposedly has to do with **caching.** Can someone explain what exactly this means and why it is holds true?

How exactly do you "cache-this," using an array rather than caching with BST?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that using a BST doesn't give you any advantage, since, even if you're caching data (which means there's some kind of locality, you may access the same element later for example), the insert operation and find operation always cost **O(h)** where h is the height of the tree. In the worst case, even **O(n)**.

Whereas using an array for caching means that of course, at first it may be linear, but whenever you access the same element of the array afterwards, if there's spatial and temporal locality, you may find yourself accessing directly the same chunks of contiguous memory repeatedly, because you already know its index, which means you have a constant time access.

Answer (score 0):

I assume caching relates to CPU caches, which come with a prefetcher which predicts your next memory accesses. So if you search sequentially in an array your prefetcher recognizes the memory access pattern and loads the memory into the CPU cache before your CPU accesses it. When the CPU actually accesses the next memory element, it is already in the cache and can be accessed quickly.
Without caches & prefetchers your CPU would have to wait for the memory controller to fetch the data from the RAM, which is quite slow in comparison to the CPU cache.

In a BST you don't do sequential access. In the worst case your BST does not reside in contiguous memory, but each node is at some arbitrary location in memory. Your prefetcher cannot predict this. The then CPU has to wait for each element to be fetched from memory.

A though without prefetchers is regarding the cache line. On x86_64 a cache line is 64 bytes long. Each integer is either 4 or 8 byte, so you can scan 16 or 8 array entries per cache line. The first access to the memory location fetches the whole line, so you only pay the memory access once for 8 comparisons.
For the BST the same argument as above applies. The node memory is likely not on the same cache line so have to do a memory access for each comparison.

To summarize: A) The memory access takes significantly more time than the comparison; B) if searching through an array or a BST is faster depends on the amount of items.